# Database design and Django Model for Contact and Enquiry

Tags: django, django-models, database-design, django-forms

I'm working on a small Django website for a photographer.

There are a contact form and a booking. A percentage of these contact leads will be lost. If the customer books, the app should be able to follow up with the customer.

I've been thinking about how to proceed and my idea is to create a contact table with the information that the customer provides from the contact form and a second table that would have a "One to One" relationship in case that the lead becomes a customer.

In a later stage after the event has happened, there will be a private access folder where the user can download his pictures. And has to be a user in order to be able to log in and have authorization and authentication.

How would you design the database and the models in Django? Any advice or considerations in order to tackle de problem in the best way possible?

[image: Database tables example]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

models.py

```
class contact(models.Model):

 user = models.OneToOneField(User)
 Phone = models.CharField(default='', max_length=20)
 event_type=models.CharField(default='',choices=create_a_list_of_choices_)
 date=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
 email=models.EmailField()
 image = models.ImageField(blank=True,upload_to='users_photos',)

class Booking(models.Model):

 User=models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
   )
 Extra=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
 Deposit=models.CharField(max_length=50)
 Time=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
 Notes=models.TextField(max_length=250,blank=True)
 Price=MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD')
```

this is how your models should look like you can add some more other fields, and for the moneyFiled you can install it by following this link :https://github.com/django-money/django-money